# Arquillian: No runnable methods

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

Trying to execute an arquillian whitebox test, I get the exception below, though the junit4 test class has @Test annotated methods.

```
    java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:169)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:31)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:65)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:90)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please post the Test class to have more information of how the test looks ?

May be this link would help : 
https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/issues/501

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Indeed there were two versions of the Test.class on the classpath. I added some dependencies via importRuntimeDependencies(). One of them was incorrectly scoped and hence imported another junit.jar.

It was very helpful to [export the generated archive](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/#export_the_deployment).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Mine was caused because I didn't use the right import for the @Test annotation. It worked with:

```
import org.junit.Test;
```